# When user is clicking on the button a flow should be executed which should open as pop up instead of sub tabs. how can i achieve this in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, visual-workflow, screen-flow

Usually when we create a button for flow to execute then it opens in the new tab or without a sidebar or header, i want after clicking on that button flow should execute as a popup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want after clicking a button a flow should execute and it should show as a popup instead of sidebar